# Quand emploie-t-on l'expression « si je peux me permettre » ?

Tags: expressions

> Je la trouve très occupée ces derniers temps, **si je peux me permettre**. Je n'envie pas le moins du monde son travail, remarque.

Est-ce que l'on utilise cette expression quand on pense être mal placé pour tenir de tels propos que l'on vient tout juste de tenir ? Ou si sa remarque risque d'offusquer ou de choquer ses interlocuteurs ?

Dans ce cas précis, je me demande si le locuteur veut dire que :

> **Loin de moi l'idée d'insinuer que je suis au courant de tout ce qu'elle fait**, mais je la trouve très occupée ces derniers temps.

Une dernière chose : je m'interroge sur une nuance entre « si je **peux** me permettre » et « si je **puis** me permettre ».

Comment: Yes, it means what you think. *Puis* is more elevated language (note that in subject-verb inversion, it's the only correct form: *Puis-je... ?*).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Hi. I wonder if the word "très" triggers the use of this expression here? : "She is **too** busy **in my humble opinion**, though it is not my place to say for certain how much work would really make her **too** busy **by her own standards**."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En effet cette expression est utilisée lorsque l'on commente ce sur quoi l'on est pas supposé intervenir, ou lorsque l'on risque de choquer lorsque la remarque s'adresse à une personne de à qui l'on est pas censé s'adresser. E.g : dire à son patron que la couleur de ses chaussettes ne s'accorde pas à celle de sa ceinture.

Dans ce cas précis, difficile à dire.... il faudrait savoir : la position du locuteur, qui l'écoute, et de qui il parle. Mais dans tous les cas, il n'insinue pas connaître l'agenda de la personne. Il pose un avis, sur l'activité en général d'une personne, pour laquelle il n'est pas censé avoir d'avis à émettre.

Je peux ou je puis sont deux formes du présent totalement équivalentes. Cependant je puis est plus... "élevé".

Answer (score 1):

[image]

La réplique «Puis-je me permettre ?» apparaît (20′43″) dans le film légendaire *Les Vacances de M. Hulot* de Tati. Dans ce film il n'y a pratiquement pas de dialogue et toutes les répliques servent uniquement à donne l'ambiance et a caractériser les personnages comme un bruit de fond. «Puis-he me permettre ?» est dit par une dame très bourgeoise qui veut se mettre à table pour déjeuner (dans le restaurant de l'hôtel), la table est vide, elle demande la permission à une autre table (!!!) et ensuite, quand monsieur Schmutz, un Alsacien, arrive avec sa famille, elle est tout de même obligée de changer de table, donc cette «permission» ne lui a servi à rien. Je pense que Tati a voulu se servir de la surenchère de précautions inhérente à cette expression : au lieu de dire «me permettez-vous ?» on demande à l'autre de nous donner la permission de nous accorder à nous-même la permission de faire quelque chose, c'est a permission au carré, cela avoisine le ridicule et Tati s'en sert merveilleusement bien pour montrer l'hypocrisie bourgeoise.

J'ai mis la scène sur [Youtube](https://youtu.be/43EDfMStzyE) pour vous permettre de la visionner.