# How do you say in French “if you don't mind my asking”?

Tags: expressions, pronoms, expressions-idiomatiques, adjectifs, noms

I'm trying to figure out how to say “if you don't mind ***my*** asking” in French, not “if you don't mind ***me*** asking”. The question that will follow will be formal.

I came up with “*si cela ne vous dérange pas mon demandant*” but Google Translate is saying it's “*si cela ne vous dérange pas de demander*”. Could someone help?

Comment: *Si je peux me permettre*, "if you don't mind *my* asking", vs "if you don't mind *me* asking", doesn't make much of a difference IMO; you can't (and shouldn't be trying to) translate it word-for-word anyway - neither literal translation makes much sense in French.

Comment: @CubbyKushi: what do you perceive to be the difference in meaning in English between "if you don't mind _me_ asking" and "if you don't mind _my_ asking"? To me there is no difference in meaning. Even if you perceive a slight difference, surely they are closer to each other in meaning than any French translation will be to either of them? There isn't a one-to-one correspondence between phrases (or words) in English and phrases (or words) in French - that's not how language works....

Comment: I can't speak for the OP but "if you don't mind me asking" seems to be about whether the listener specifically minds the person who is asking (for having done so), while "if you don't mind my asking" is about whether the listener minds the asking itself (but nothing to do with feelings toward the person _for_ asking).  In practice I'm not sure it has ever made much of a difference, but there _is_ a difference... I guess.

Comment: @Darren The first to me asks if the person specifically minds the person asking, so the difference between them is negligible.  What you implied would be more like "If you don't mind my presence, may I ask...".

Answer (score 13):

The most formal way would be:

> Si je puis me permettre, (question)

Note that you could also use the interrogative form:

> Puis-je me permettre de vous demander (question)?

I think this is as formal as it can be and is the one I would use.

I would say the "enquiquiner" proposal is really not formal.

Comment: *Puis-je me permettre de vous demander (question)?* - this is more like *May I ask you (something)?*

Comment: in the first one it should be "peux" and not "puis". They both have the same formality just different forms.

Comment: I agree with @Franck, « je puis » sounds old fashioned. Although, note that's it's the standard when asking a question: « puis-je » and never « peux-je* ». Though, « est-ce que je peux… » is probably more common.

Answer (score 8):

I would interprete it as:

> Si vous me permettez de poser la question...

So for example

> How old are you, if you don't mind me asking...
>
> Quel âge avez-vous, si vous me permettez de vous poser cette
>   question...?

After the relevant discussion I am not 100% sure if there is but the slightest difference between me/my asking structure. The difference is rather a grammatical one. In any case I think that French interpretations would be the same.

---

I strongly suggest you to use (apart Google Translate which is very good for quick translations)

https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais

So for instance

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/if+you+don%27t+mind+me+asking.html

Also another useful web page is

http://www.wordreference.com/fren/

yet another one

https://www.deepl.com/home

Comment: Je vous remercie pour le site Internet. :) C'est utile! I need to know how to say 'If you don't mind 'MY' asking' not ;If you don't mind me asking.'

Comment: There is a slight difference between the two English if I am correct. But still I would use something along the same lines. See the Edit.

Comment: So the french equivalent of 'if you don't mind my asking' is 'si vous permettez ma question' ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. I am neither French or English native but I speak both of these languages (I hope at least:-)!). I made an attempt to interprete the English sentence into French.  Based on the discussion here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308746/if-you-dont-mind-me-asking-or-if-you-dont-mind-my-asking I don't see such a big difference between the two versions (me versus my); that's why my attempts are so closely related. Nevertheless, I suggest you to provide more information about the context (formal/informal, direct/indirect question and so on). See also jlliagre's reply.

Comment: As an English speaker I would translate both versions the same into French. T'en fais pas !

Comment: @dimitris _There is a slight difference between the two..._ I'd really love to know what difference you and the OP perceive between _...my asking_ and _...me asking_. They are identical in meaning - it is not unusual in language to have many phrases that mean exactly the same.

Comment: @OscarBravo For me either there was not a difference. In the beginning I didn't notice that it was about "my" and I respond with "me" in mind. Then I read the discussion here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308746/if-you-dont-mind-me-asking-or-if-you-dont-mind-my-asking and I thought that (may be) there is a (very) slight difference for the English natives. Still I am not convinced and furthermore I consider that in any case the French interpretation would be more or less the same.

Comment: @dimitris There is a _grammatical_ difference but there is no _semantic_ difference. BUt you don't translate grammar - you translate semantics.

Comment: @OscarBravo Thanks for the comment. Should I modify the answer?

Comment: French speaker here, out of the two « Quel âge… » questions, the first one sounds natural, while the second sounds a bit awkward. Not more formal, just odd. As a rule of thumb, the longer the sentence, the more formal it may be (outside of fixed popular expressions such as « est-ce que… »). « Permettre qch (to so.) » has a very king-ish style to it. That would probably be fine if you're asking the President a personal question (and it would sound odd anyway). When you ask the second question, to me, it feels like you assume it will be censored (and I mean censored as in no freedom of speech).

Comment: I agree that there's little (even no, as per @OscarBravo ) difference in meaning between the 2 Eng versions. Imo, the best way to try to make the distinction that some see in Eng would be to use the passive (“If you don’t mind being asked, ...?”), but even w/that, the question is “being asked” by someone so an objection to answering could still be based on “who’s asking” & not on “what’s being asked.” (Anyway, I doubt if my "passive option" would be acceptable in French [“Si ça ne te dérange pas d'être demandé, …”] or even understandable considering that “être [très] demandé”=“in high demand”)

Comment: @PapaPoule IMO there's a slight difference in tone. "Me" brings the *persons* into it: e.g., "You and me, we might have a problem ... you might mind (i.e. object to) me." -- whereas "my" is along the lines of, "there's such a thing as unwanted behaviour but there's no bad people ... you might object to my *asking*, but I'm not going to suggest  you'd ever object to me." So "me" sounds a bit personally insecure, and "my" sounds more open and bold. In "me asking", "me" is the object of the dislike and "asking" describes or qualifies me -- in "my asking", the asking is the object of the dislike.

Answer (score 7):

You do not tell the context, whether a formal or informal question is expected, to whom you ask the question (*tu* or *vous*) but I would suggest anyway :

> Si ma question ne te dérange pas / ne vous dérange pas, xxxx ?

The first part of your attempt was correct French: *si cela ne vous dérange pas* however, the end *mon demandant* doesn't work in French. I believe "my asking" means *my question* so translates to *ma question* but you shouldn't try to stick too much to the English form.

Here is another suggestion :

> [Si je peux me permettre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23099/quand-emploie-t-on-lexpression-si-je-peux-me-permettre) (une question), xxxx ?

Comment: @Eric that's correct, it's against "ma question", 3rd person singular - regardless of the "te" or "vous"

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the context,

> Sans vouloir être indiscret,...

could work. For example :

> Sans vouloir être indiscret, quel âge avez vous ?

It isn't an exact translation but is idiomatic and conveys the same meaning. It is clear that a sensitive question is coming right after.

Answer (score 1):

The most formal way to say it would be

> Si je puis me permettre…

(The form *je puis* of the verb *pouvoir* is more formal than *je peux* and is used only in expressions like this one.)

You can also apologize for your curiosity by saying

> Excusez ma curiosité, mais…

And more strongly

> Désolé de vous enquiquiner, mais j'avais une question à vous poser…

and the answer will be «Mais non, vous ne m'enquiquinez pas» followed by the answer to your question.

Comment: "Enquiquiner" sounds very much France-French (?), and not quite formal. Depending on the context it might even raise an eyebrow or two (in Quebec-French anyway).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes, this is indeed France origin french and not International french.

Comment: And very old-fashionned if you ask me... It would be hard to use in day-to-day speach without amusing at least a few people...

Comment: @LaurentS. Getting a smile from the asked person could be a good start!

Comment: It is not formal in the sense of written-formal speech, but it is formal when you want to address somebody with respect. Maybe some more insight on the context of the query would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**I came up with 'si cela ne vous dérange pas mon demandant' but Google Translate is saying it's 'si cela ne vous dérange pas de demander'. Could someone help**

In the phrase "my asking", the word "asking" is grammatically [a gerund](https://linguapress.com/grammar/gerunds.htm):

> The gerund is a verb which is used as if it were a noun ... [for example] "Seeing is believing"

It's formed from the present participle of the verb.

French verbs have a present participle (e.g. *manger* / *mangeant*) but I think they're not used as gerunds i.e. as nouns. You could never say *bon mangeant* in French like you might say "good eating" in American English.

Instead I think the French tend to use the infinitive form of the verb, e.g. *bon à manger* ("good for to eat" also known as "good food"), or *voir c'est croire*.

So *mon demandant* is no good. If you want to use a noun in the phrase, you say *ma question*.

---

Also I think that asking, "If **you** don't mind..." is slightly rude: perhaps it's imposing on *you* to decide.
So a slightly politer English version (which doesn't ask you to commit yourself before you've even heard my request) might be to ask, "If I may, ...".
That's where other answers are suggesting *Si je peux* or *Si je puis*.

Also, the distinction in English between "If I may" and "If I can" is, in French, the difference between *pouvoir* and *permettre*.
Again, I think it's more polite to say "If I may permit myself to..." than "If you will permit me to..." -- I think you're expected to be well-behaved, to govern your own behaviour, to know what's right and wrong, and to not impose that responsibility on others.
That's where another answer suggests *Si je peux me permettre* instead of *Si vous me le permettez*.
Sometimes if you get a cold-call, i.e. a business phone call from someone you don't know, they'll explain the reason (i.e. why they're allowing themselves to call you) by starting, *Je me permets de vous contacter parce que...*

Comment: Je vous remercie. Je l'ai trouvé vraiment instructif ! :) Can you just confirm the following: both 'je peux me permettre' and 'je puis me permettre' mean the same thing, however the latter is more formal than the former.

Comment: I think they're the same, just *puis* is more courtly, literary (and not current) -- it's *soutenu*.